# Trying to get a terminal to work in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs, ssh, cygwin

I've been having a lot of problems with emacs and trying to get the terminal to work with:

```
    M-x term
```

I installed cygwin and I fixed up my .emacs to include the paths:

```
    (setenv "PATH" (concat "c:/cygwin/bin;" (getenv "PATH")))
    (setq exec-path (cons "c:/cygwin/bin" exec-path))
    (require 'cygwin-mount)
    (cygwin-mount-activate)
    (add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions
    'shell-strip-ctrl-m nil t)
    (add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions
    'comint-watch-for-password-prompt nil t)
    (setq explicit-shell-file-name "bash.exe")
    ;; For subprocesses invoked via the shell
    ;; (e.g., "shell -c command")
    (setq shell-file-name explicit-shell-file-name)
```

However now when I launch terminal, it seems to give nothing but a blank screen and "hang"

When I launch:

```
    M-x shell
```

It does indeed launch the bash shell and flying around the file directories is okay (with cd, ls, cp, rm, etc.). However, when I do something like try to open up a Python shell, it again hands, and I type in ... and the shell crashes. Is there anything significantly wrong with what I am doing or perhaps somebody could direct me towards solutions online? (I've looked quite extensively.)

SSH also gives the error:

"Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the default 'Cygwin Bash Shell'?  This is the one that launches inside a Windows cmd shell, and you can't drag to resize the screen.  This shell is horribly broken, because of the underlying Windows component.  Try using something like **rxvt**, or one of the putty forks.

If this is all set, then the issue is likely a termcap issue.  Some people set their Cygwin TERM variable to 'xterm', because many remote machines don't have termcaps installed for things like `rxvt-cygwin-native`.  Overridding it locally will cause problems with programs that attempt a range of terminal operations.

In your ~/.bash_profile, you can set your terminal to the following. `export TERM=rxvt-cygwin-native`

See my [rxvt install guide and tips](http://www.theeggeadventure.com/wikimedia/index.php/Rxvt) for more on rxvt.

Comment: Having trouble setting up rxvt through .emacs...saying '-i is not an option' and lists possible options. What is the default setting for the TERM variable? I found sources online saying it's set to CYGWIN, however, I don't know if this is the batch file or some other hidden file? Hard to get a shell in emacs, I guess. Thanks a lot for the input though!

Answer (score 1):

> SSH also gives the error:
>
> "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a
>   terminal."

To solve this problem in NTEmacs (NOT cygwin's emacs), I did the following:

1. Install cygwin's gcc
2. Use it to compile [fakecygpty.c](https://github.com/Shougo/fakecygpty/blob/master/fakecygpty.c) into fakecygpty.exe
3. Run `fakecygpty ssh my_server` instead of just `ssh my_server` in an emacs shell (easiest if fakecygpty is on your path).

I tested this in `*shell*` running cmd, cygwin bash, and git bash, and they all work fine. My understanding is that fakecygpty.c present NTEmacs as a valid cygwin tty so that ssh is willing to talk to it. [More information about fakecygpty and SSH with ntemacs.](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SshWithNTEmacs#toc2)

---

You can also make NTEmacs edit files properly over SSH by adding this to init.el:

```
(eval-after-load "tramp"
  '(progn
     (add-to-list 'tramp-methods
                  (mapcar
                   (lambda (x)
                     (cond
                      ((equal x "sshx") "cygssh")
                      ((eq (car x) 'tramp-login-program) (list 'tramp-login-program "fakecygpty ssh"))
                      (t x)))
                   (assoc "sshx" tramp-methods)))
     (setq tramp-default-method "cygssh")))
```

I also needed to update my Tramp to 2.2.7 to be able to edit files over ssh from ntemacs.

Hope this saves someone some trouble. :)